# Copy multiples files listed in a text file from source subfolders to a new folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy

I need to find a number of 500 image files, of which names I have listed in a text file (a single filename per line). The search is to be done in all subfolders of an external HDD and all files are to be copied to local drive.

```
pushd D:\move_script
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('type List.txt') do xcopy /hrkvy ".\SourceFolder\%%a" ".\DestinationFolder"
popd
```

Files not found in SourceFolder.There are multiple subfolders in directory D:\move_script
So how i mentioned the sourcefolder so that it can search files in all subfolders under D:\move_script .

When i use the single sourcefolder like in the below command then its searched files only under data folder and copied to destination folder.

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('type List.txt') do xcopy /hrkvy ".\**data**\%%a" ".\DestinationFolder"
```

Please help what is wrong for search source subfolders.

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is! From what you've submitted, it looks like you're complaining about the search being limited to either `.\SourceFolder` or `.\**data**`, when you wanted to search with the current directory `.` as the base. What is the purpose of using those two unwanted directories as the base of your recursion, if you don't want it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AIUI, the problem is to copy the files named in the `list.txt` file from wherever they exist in the source subtree to the destination directory.

An issue with your code: You have used a `pushd/popd` bracket, which means that between the `pushd` and the `popd`, the current directory is (the argument to the `PUSHD`)

The `.` in the term `".\SourceFolder\%%a"` means the directory **relative to the current directory** - and the current directory is `D:\move_script`, so the source interpreted by `xcopy` is `"D:\move_script\SourceFolder\%%a"`

The easy way to fix this is to remove the `pushd/popd` commands, and execute
 `D:\move_script\thisbatchname`

which will execute the remaining command relative to the directory selected at the time of execution.

There is a problem with the approach. Given that the `xcopy` could be fixed to perform the copy of the one file in the source subtree that matches the name in `%%a`, that search would need to be done 500 times - once for each entry in `list.txt`, which would be v.e.r.y. .s.l.o.w.

So here's another approach:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the directory and filename are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q78088112.txt"

(
FOR /f "delims=" %%e IN ('XCOPY /L /Y /S "%sourcedir%\*"') DO ECHO %%e^|%%~nxe
)>"%temp%\####.exist"
(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%e IN ("%filename1%") DO ECHO ^|%%e
)>"%temp%\####.incl"

FOR /f "tokens=1delims=|" %%e IN ('findstr /e /L /g:"%temp%\####.incl" "%temp%\####.exist"') DO ECHO COPY "%%e" "destdirname"

DEL "%temp%\####.excl" "%temp%\####.exist"
GOTO :eof
```

Note that if the filename does not contain separators like spaces, then both `usebackq` and the quotes around `%filename1%` can be  omitted.

The required COPY commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO COPY` to `COPY` to actually copy the files. Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file copied`)

First, perform an `xcopy` listing, creating a full filelist in a temporary file `####.exist` with each line of the format `fullfilename|filenameandextension`

Next, process the filename list to `####.incl`, simply inserting a `|` before each filename

Then find the first token of the lines in `####.exist` using `|` as a delimiter (which becomes the full filename of the file to be copied) WHERE the line `/e` ends with any entry in the `/g:` file, `####.incl`

Note that `|` cannot appear in a legitimate filename.

Comment: Hi Magoo , When i executing it getting error. I have changed source , filename1 and destination.I have mentioned only some code here.                                                              
@ECHO OFF
SET "sourcedir=D:\move_script"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\list.txt"                                                                                                                               
FOR /f "tokens=1delims=|" %%e IN ('findstr /e /L /g:"%temp%\####.incl" "%temp%\####.exist"') DO COPY "%%e" "D:\found"                                 

Error: Cannot perform a cyclic copy

Comment: I have List.txt file content is.                                                                                                        test.txt                              
test.pdf                 
test1.txt                                                                                                            
test2.txt                                                                                   
test3.txt

Comment: please help.   Error: Cannot perform a cyclic copy

Comment: `Cannot perform a cyclic copy` would indicate that the source directory tree forms part of the destination directory tree (or vice-versa). Have you solved this problem? (If yes, please add a comment about how you solved it)

Comment: I solved it by changing the destination and source directories.